# Is the meaning of "on your own" clear in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> -- Are you travelling on your own?
> -- I'm travelling by Flixbus.
> -- I mean, are you travelling with your friends or family, or on your own?
> -- I'm travelling alone.

This scene took place at customs. Was the original question clear enough to understand that the questioner wasn't asking about the means of transport?

Although [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_one%27s_own) treats the two meanings as one, [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-ones-own) lists them separately and I think it even proves that the questioner was unclear, perhaps even linguistically wrong.

Comment: The question was perfectly clear. The initial answer is a non sequitur. Both dictionaries seem to say the same thing, to my mind.

Comment: Collins' second meaning ('without help from other people') isn't really relevant here, unless the traveller was walking!

Comment: What @DoneWithThis said. The passengers initial response is the problem, not the original question. Ordinarily I'd say all the customs guy cares about is whether you're traveling with other people ***on the same ticket***. He probably doesn't even care if you plan on meeting up with friends traveling on the same ferry or plane, if the ticket sales aren't connected. He *certainly* doesn't care if you got to the airport on a bus filled with dozens of people you don't know.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about logic / common sense, not language

Answer (score 0):

The request for clarification seems reasonable:

"Are you traveling alone?"
"I'm traveling by Flixbus (on a common transport, with other passengers), so not alone."

The questioner then clarifies that they want to know whether the traveler is accompanied by friends or relatives, not strangers.

There's no error there on either side. It's just the usual zeroing in on the exact meaning in speech.

Comment: Honestly, I think the responder completely failed to grasp the question. At customs, how many people are going to be arriving or departing in their own single-seater transportation?

Comment: @DoneWithThis. So for you arriving in one's own car can't be "on one's own" because car isn't a "single-seater transportation" - do I understand you correctly?

Comment: No. The guy at customs isn't vaguely interested in how you got to the airport, or would leave from it [depending on whether you're about to take off or have just landed] whether by bus, train, taxi, bicycle - he just doesn't care. All he wants to know is if you, amongst the hundreds of others who will be getting on the same aircraft/train/long-haul bus, are travelling with friends, family, business associates etc… or alone.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. - people who regularly travel to countries outside their own will tell you that you have to pass through 'customs' only when you enter a country from outside. Customs officers want to know what goods you are bringing into their country, and whether those goods include items that are forbidden or subject to tax. The guy asking you if you are travelling on your own is much more likely to be an immigration officer, seeking to find out whether the purpose of your visit is a permitted one.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - maybe so, but I fail to see what relevance that has to the OP's question, or this answer.

Comment: @DoneWithThis.- it addresses various apparent misconceptions in your comments above.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - It addresses only whether it was 'customs' as stated by the OP, or 'immigration'. It really is of no import whatsoever to the understanding of question or answer. It could have been the ticket office or check-in clerk & still make no material difference.